# shortcode doesnt work on excerpt

Tags: shortcode, excerpt

My shortcodes don't seem on archive page excerpts. You can see an example excerpt:

https://unit-test-data.deniz-tasarim.site/2011/03/15/

here is related code with an excerpt in my theme files:

> archive.php:

```
<h3><?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
<p class="project-dp-one"><?php the_excerpt(); //html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?></p>
<a class="btn btn-lg ulockd-btn-thm2" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( ' Read More', 'hekim' )?></a>
```

> function.php:

```
function hekim_excerpt_lenght_number(){
    global $redux_demo;
    if ( is_numeric($redux_demo['text-excerpt-length'])==1 ) {
        add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function( $length ) {
            global $redux_demo;
            return $redux_demo['text-excerpt-length']; } );
    }
    else {
        add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function( $length ) { return 11; } );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'hekim_excerpt_lenght_number' );
```

---

```
// Custom Excerpts
/*-
function html5wp_index($length) // Create 20 Word Callback for Index page Excerpts, call using html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index');
{
    return 2;
}

// Create 40 Word Callback for Custom Post Excerpts, call using html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_custom_post');
function html5wp_custom_post($length)
{
    return 40;
}
*/
// Create the Custom Excerpts callback
function html5wp_excerpt($length_callback = '', $more_callback = '')
{
    global $post;
    if (function_exists($length_callback)) {
        add_filter('excerpt_length', $length_callback);
    }
    if (function_exists($more_callback)) {
        add_filter('excerpt_more', $more_callback);
    }
    $output = get_the_excerpt();
    $output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
    $output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
    $output = '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
    echo esc_html_e( $output, 'hekim' );
}
```

---

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop'); // Remove auto <p> tags in Excerpt (Manual Excerpts only)
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode'); // Allows Shortcodes to be executed in Excerpt (Manual Excerpts only)

add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode', 5 );

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'hekim_html5_blank_view_article'); // Add 'View Article' button instead of [...] for Excerpts

//remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop'); // Remove <p> tags from Excerpt altogether
```

---

**how can I show shortcodes on excerpts?**

Comment: Are you sure the file is named `function.php` and not `functions.php`? I notice you're filtering the excerpt APIs but you don't use those APIs and instead use a `html5wp_excerpt` function. I also only see one excerpt in your code, and it has mangled a block HTML, and does not contain a shortcode

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, functions.php.I wrote false to question.yes, I dont use html5wp_excerpt.how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do these posts have manual excerpts? Do you have an example excerpt/content that can be used to replicate the problem?

Comment: @TomJNowell manuel excepts is empy.it is unit test xml file